# Debug Magento 2 checkout jsLayout

Tags: magento2, javascript

In [onepage.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml#L21) the `#checkout` component is initialized using the settings from a json generated by the block object `$block->getJsLayout();` :

```
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#checkout": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I see the output of this json using the browser console, without changing the `.phtml` by adding a `console.log` in there ?

Answer (score 10):

### Debug Magento 2 Checkout Js Layout

#### View Page Source

Using View page source (Ctrl + U). We can see the Json render.

[image]

And then using http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to re-format the Json.

[image]

#### We can add to a global Js variable

In one page template, we can see:

```
<script>
    window.checkoutConfig = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getCheckoutConfig()); ?>;
    // Create aliases for customer.js model from customer module
    window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
    window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
</script>
```

These are the global Js variables. So, we can do the same. For example:

```
window.checkoutJsLayout = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
```

In your browser console, we can check `window.checkoutJsLayout`.

Comment: I am trying to find some other solution rather  than editing the phtml file. 
The info should be there, right ? We just need to find the JS trick to get it.

Comment: You should use View Page source if you don't want to touch the phtml file. It is a good way.