# Magento2 Checkout Customization

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

I need help with checkout customization. 
Can someone give me some links to resourses with information about Magento 2 checkout customization?  I am all ready readed developer guide and docs, but i still dont understand how to show additional parameters depending on the chosen shipment method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Overview the frontend technology stacks

#### Require JS

http://requirejs.org/

We also need to know how to override the Js and template html via Require Js. For example, we will override the shipping js and shipping html template:

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js`
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`

In your custom module, create `requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping':
                'Vendor_YourModule/js/view/shipping', // <= Override the Js

            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html':
                'Vendor_YourModule/template/shipping.html' // <= Override the html template
        }
    }
};
```

#### KnockoutJs Template

http://knockoutjs.com/

For example, go to `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js`:

```
    ......
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping'
        },
    ......
```

On the checkout page, Magento will be rendered by using Knockout templates.
We can find the Knockout template under `pub/static` or`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template`. We can use Require Js to override these templates.

#### Layout render and how to debug

One of the most important skills of a good developer is the debugging skill:
[Debug Magento 2 checkout jsLayout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140508/debug-magento-2-checkout-jslayout/140514#140514)

Magento will load and merge the layout from `checkout_index_index.xml`.

Take a look these files to see more details:

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml`

### Practical examples

Please, practice some good samples:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html

We can follow the logic of checkout agreements - `vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements` to add more content: add a static block, static content, etc.

Comment: Do you know how to manipulate the values when passed to the server side?

Comment: could you please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316585/how-to-edit-checkout-page-code-in-magento-2