# Magento 2.2.5: Custom checkout

Tags: magento2, template, knockoutjs

I'm working on Custom Checkout Module.

I've Created a Custom module follow this devdocs:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html
 and everything is working fine, but i cant use knockout js to render item using "`displayArea`" and "`getRegion`".

So here is what i've done:
[image]
As you can see, the "`getRegion`" part doesn't work. It doesn't render anything.

My code:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\MagentoCheckoutCustom\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml (this file i do exactly what the devdoc said, except for the "`displayArea`" named "`delivery-fieldsets`", because devdoc doesn't say anything about that, so i was trying to put it everywhere that i thing it may work, but still no luck).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="before-shipping-method-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">delivery-fieldsets</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="delivery-group" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Aht_MagentoCheckoutCustom/js/view/custom-shipping</item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="delivery_instruction" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                                <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress</item>
                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                            <!-- value element allows to specify default value of the form field -->
                                                                            <!--<item name="value" xsi:type="string">Yout value here</item>-->
                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.delivery_instruction</item>
                                                                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Delivery Instruction:</item>
                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <item name="delivery_type" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                                                                                <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress</item>
                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Delivery Type 1</item>
                                                                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">delivery_type_1</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Delivery Type 2</item>
                                                                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">delivery_type_2</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Delivery Type 3</item>
                                                                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">delivery_type_3</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                            <!-- value element allows to specify default value of the form field -->
                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.delivery_type</item>
                                                                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Delivery Type:</item>
                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\MagentoCheckoutCustom\view\frontend\web\js\view\custom-shipping.js

```
/**


* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'uiRegistry',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service'
], function (
    $,
    _,
    Component,
    ko,
    customer,
    addressList,
    addressConverter,
    quote,
    createShippingAddress,
    selectShippingAddress,
    shippingRatesValidator,
    formPopUpState,
    shippingService,
    selectShippingMethodAction,
    rateRegistry,
    setShippingInformationAction,
    stepNavigator,
    modal,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    checkoutData,
    registry,
    $t
) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Aht_MagentoCheckoutCustom/custom-shipping',
            deliveryFormTemplate: 'Aht_MagentoCheckoutCustom/shipping-delivery/delivery-form'
        },
        visible: ko.observable(!quote.isVirtual()),
        errorValidationMessage: ko.observable(false),
        isCustomerLoggedIn: customer.isLoggedIn,
        isFormPopUpVisible: formPopUpState.isVisible,
        isFormInline: addressList().length === 0,
        isNewAddressAdded: ko.observable(false),
        saveInAddressBook: 1,
        quoteIsVirtual: quote.isVirtual()
    });
});
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\MagentoCheckoutCustom\view\frontend\web\template\custom-shipping.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<!-- custom delivery-->

<li id="delivery" class="checkout-shipping-delivery" data-bind="fadeVisible: visible()">
    <div class="step-title" translate="'Delivery'" data-role="title" />
    <div id="checkout-step-delivery"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <!-- Inline address form -->
        <render args="deliveryFormTemplate" />
    </div>
</li>
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\MagentoCheckoutCustom\view\frontend\web\template\shipping-delivery\delivery-form.html (it goes to this file succesfully, but some how, it stopped at the "`getRegion`" part and i dont know why.)

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<!-- delivery-fieldsets -->
<!-- before-shipping-method-form -->

<form class="form form-shipping-delivery" id="co-shipping-delivery-form" data-bind="attr: {'data-hasrequired': $t('* Required Fields')}">
    <div id="shipping-delivery" class="fieldset delivery">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('delivery-fieldsets') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's what i've read (its all good post tho :D ):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847615/magento2-knockout-render-specific-child

[Magento2 Checkout Customization](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143252/magento2-checkout-customization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I was come to devdoc and read again, and i've realize that i've missing 1 step to create input, it need 2 step

```
<item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">%your_module_dir%/js/view/custom-checkout-form</item>
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">%your_module_dir%/custom-checkout-form</item>
    </item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="custom-checkout-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- uiComponent is used as a wrapper for form fields (its template will render all children as a list) -->
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
            <!-- the following display area is used in template (see below) -->
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-fields</item>
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
              //your item here
```

As you can see, it require 2 step to make this work, 1 is "`custom-checkout-form-container`" and 2 is "`custom-checkout-form-fieldset`", but i only do 1, so that why it doesn't work. :)

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html