# How to edit checkout page code in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, theme, checkout-page

My website checkout page is https://mywebsite.com/checkout/

Could anyone please tell me where is this page in my magento directory

Because i want to add some code in checkout page . Currently i have 2 payment gateway. I want to hide one payment gateway some time based on some conditions .

for example i have to execute the following code in my checkout page

```
$items = $cart->getItems();
            $ter = 0;
            $mes=0;
            
            
            foreach($items as $item){
                
                $attribute1 = $item->getProduct()->getData('mynewattribute');
               
                if($attribute1){
                    $ter++;
                    $mes++;
                }else{
                    $ter--;
                }
            }
            
            and some code
```

Comment: please provide screenshots rather than links that way we can see what you mean without having to go through some untrusted https link, the conditions whether or not to show a payment method should be handleble in the payment gateway module btw. i have been working on a payment gateway module and it hides whenever the currency is not whatever it's supported currency is